# При установке browser-cookie3 "pip3 install browser-cookie3" происходит ошибка

Tags: python, python-3.x

python 3.10.1
При установке browser-cookie3 "pip3 install browser-cookie3" происходит ошибка. Другие библиотеки подключаются без ошибок.[image: Ошибка]

Comment: Так вроде бы написано же в ошибках английским по черному, что вам нужно установить Microsoft Visual C++ версии 14.0 или выше.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте установить `wheel`

```
pip install wheel
```

И после этого повторить установку

```
pip install browser-cookie3
```

**UPD**

Также ошибка гласит о том, что вам необходимо установить Microsoft C++ Build Tools. [Ссылка](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/) для различных платформ и интерфейсов на установку